# Getting backend data with ReactJS as front-end and PHP as backend

Tags: php, reactjs

I am trying to work with ReactJS (16.x) as a front-end and PHP (5.x) as a backend. I am calling the API using Axios. I have a shared Linux hosting where I am trying to upload the project. It is showing CORS issues and any method apart from GET is getting 301 Moved Permanently and then the same call is occurring with OPTIONS and GET respectively.

I have tried adding CORS to the PHP code but it is not working.

These are the headers that I am using to avoid the CORS issue.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    // header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://temp.mkconsultants.co.in/");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token , Authorization');
```

Comment: have you solved your problem or not?

Comment: One part is solved. Another I am stuck now as mentioned in the comment section of the answer given by @Vyas

Comment: add your request code front and back both side as well and where are you handling it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function cors() {

    // Allow from any origin
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        // Decide if the origin in $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] is one
        // you want to allow, and if so:
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            // may also be using PUT, PATCH, HEAD etc
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);
    }

    echo "You have CORS!";
}
```

Comment: It is solved now. I am able to make the calls. But, I am not getting the payload on the server-side (PHP). I am trying a POST call and passing some payload. I am trying to access it in PHP using $_POST. But, I am getting an empty array even though I can see my parameters in Networks tab of Google Chrome.